# Error android.view.InflateException, unable to inflate MapView class

Tags: android

I am facing this problem where i get a runtime exception android.view.InflateException and traces the error in the xml file where i have declared the MapView using the Map API key and says that the MapView cant be inflated...
i have two activities where one activity invokes this class containing the mapView, earlier when i had just one activity ,it was working fine.
Thanx in advance

XML File:

```
<view class="com.google.android.maps.MapView"
 android:id="@+id/myMapView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_x="0px"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="removedtheapikeybecauseitssuppoedtobesecrut" 
    android:layout_y="105px" /> 

Activity 1

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

Log.i("MyActivity", "MyClass.getView() — get item number ");

try
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnSubmit);

        EditText range= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditRange);

        EditText EditRange = null;

        String value= EditRange.getText().toString();

        final Bundle bundle= new Bundle();

        bundle.putString("param1",value);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
         public void onClick(View view) 
{
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), RoutePath.class);

         myIntent.putExtras(bundle);

          startActivity(myIntent);
     }

        });

        }

        catch(Exception e)

        {
            Log.d("My Activity",e.getMessage());

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Activity 2

public class RoutePath extends MapActivity
{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {   

        //View  view;
        //Context context;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.myMapView1);

        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you are using

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

for RoutePath. Pretty sure you should be using a different xml here.

Comment: oh m sorry...m using two different xml files as the UI is different main2.xml for activity 1 and main.xml for activity2...i fixed it and made the necessary changes in setContentViiew() but nw i m having a force close error

Comment: Hey thanks reno...i fixed the error....Sorry for bothering as it was a minuscule..